# select sum until a specific line is found

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE Coins (Badge VARCHAr(10), Cointype INT,  Number INT);

INSERT INTO Coins (Badge,Cointype, Number) VALUES
('' , 1, 1),
('' , 5, 2),
('' , 20, 3),
('' , 1, 4),
('' , 5, 5),
('' , 5, 6),
('' , 5, 7),
('RESET', 0 , 0),
('' , 1, 8),
('' , 10, 9),
('RESET', 0 , 0),
('' , 5, 10),
('' , 20, 11);
```

Hi, with this table I want to have the following sum above the first line ('RESET',0,0)

```
select 
SUM(case when Cointype=1 Then Number else 0 END) as SUM1,
SUM(case when Cointype=5 Then Number else 0 END) as SUM5,
SUM(case when Cointype=20 Then Number else 0 END) as SUM20
from Coins
```

result must be this:

```
SUM1    SUM5    SUM20
5       20      3
```

Is this possible in MySql?

in the real situation, there is also an ID and timestamp field. the top record is the most recent record with the highest ID and timestamp.
So the most recent records must summarized until the RESET line. (in case we need ordering, this is possible with the ID or timestamp field)

Then the table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Coins (ID INT, Badge VARCHAr(10), Cointype INT,  Number INT);

INSERT INTO Coins (ID, Badge,Cointype, Number) VALUES
(13,'' , 1, 1),
(12,'' , 5, 2),
(11,'' , 20, 3),
(10,'' , 1, 4),
(9,'' , 5, 5),
(8,'' , 5, 6),
(7,'' , 5, 7),
(6,'RESET', 0 , 0),
(5,'' , 1, 8),
(4,'' , 10, 9),
(3,'RESET', 0 , 0),
(2,'' , 5, 10),
(1,'' , 20, 11);
```

Comment: That's not really how relational databases work. Tables have no inherent ordering, you can't guarantee your fields would be read in the same order they were added, especially when doing an aggregate (i.e. where using an ORDER BY clause doesn't make sense). Better to record the timestamp of the "Reset" actions in a separate table, and then use  a WHERE clause to limit the query which SUMs the Coins table to return rows BETWEEN two given timestamps of your choosing.

Comment: A "CoinSequence" table with "start" and "stop" timestamp fields might make sense, then you can easily pick out the beginning and end of a particular run of coins.

Comment: To answer your question "Is this possible in MySQL?", yes it is possible. Basically, using the timestamp or column, you get the MAX(timestamp) of a row of type reset, and include only those rows with a later timestamp.

Comment: I changed the table with a ID field (autonumber)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an autonumeric column:

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e795e/3)**

```
select 
    SUM(case when Cointype=1 Then Number else 0 END) as SUM1,
    SUM(case when Cointype=5 Then Number else 0 END) as SUM5,
    SUM(case when Cointype=20 Then Number else 0 END) as SUM20
from Coins 
WHERE ID < ( SELECT MIN(ID)
             FROM Coins
             WHERE Badge = 'RESET' )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| SUM1 | SUM5 | SUM20 |
|------|------|-------|
|    5 |   20 |     3 |
```

**EDIT:**

After you change your sample looks like you have the rows in inverse order. Then you need `MAX()` instead of `MIN()`

```
select 
    SUM(case when Cointype=1 Then Number else 0 END) as SUM1,
    SUM(case when Cointype=5 Then Number else 0 END) as SUM5,
    SUM(case when Cointype=20 Then Number else 0 END) as SUM20
from Coins 
WHERE ID > ( SELECT MAX(ID)
             FROM Coins
             WHERE Badge = 'RESET' )
```

Comment: Yes the table is sorted desc. :)  Great & a very Big Thank you for helping.

Comment: It would be impossible or very difficult though, to retrieve the results of a previous session (i.e. between two resets, or from the start to the first reset), if that were required. A relational database should make it straightforward to run a similar query on any of the data, not just the most recent. Hence why I think the data structure is flawed (see earlier comment on the question itself).

Comment: @ADyson I saw your comment. But I thing this answer OP question, or do you any problem? I don't see anything regarding data between two resets

Comment: No it's not specifically mentioned, but then again in software people rarely ask for what they really want. Part of a developer's job is to check and clarify the exact requirement and think about the unseen problems. So yeah your code answers the specific question but IMHO it's not a sustainable solution for the overall system. As soon as someone wants a report covering the last 12 months it falls over.

Comment: @ADyson I see. My suggestion you can ask for clarification. But don't try to answer things  beyond the question otherwise you never be able to finish any answer. The last total sound like a very reasonable request. If OP need anything else he can ask another question.

Comment: in this case we only need the last sum until reset.  Coins are added to a box.  When we empty the box we send a reset to the database and we start counting again.

Comment: remember accept the answer with the green tick if solve your issue.

Comment: @Vanessa and if you forget to run the query before emptying the box next time? Or you suspect a mistake or fraud, or you need to analyse the takings over a long period of time? The this structure is a poor solution.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I agree you can't predict every requirement, but reporting over time, and re-running old queries are pretty obvious ones which always crop up, even if the customer claims they don't need them they always do in the end. Anyway have an upvote for solving the immediate question.